# How do I write this decoding the json only one time?

Tags: php, json

How do I write this decoding the json only one time?

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.xmlcharts.com/cache/precious-metals.php?format=json'); 

          $json = ($content);

          foreach (json_decode($content, true) as $currency => $arr) { 
            foreach ($arr as $commodity => $price) { 
                if($currency == "usd" and $commodity =="gold")
              {
                $gold_price = round($price, 2);
              }
            } 
          }


          foreach (json_decode($content, true) as $currency => $arr) { 
            foreach ($arr as $commodity => $price) { 
                if($currency == "usd" and $commodity =="silver")
              {
                $silver_price = round($price, 2);
              }
            } 
          }


          foreach (json_decode($content, true) as $currency => $arr) { 
            foreach ($arr as $commodity => $price) { 
                if($currency == "usd" and $commodity =="platinum")
              {
                $platinum_price = round($price, 2);
              }
            } 
          }
```

Comment: $json = json_decode($content, true);

Comment: Why do you loop through it three times? You can do it with one.

Comment: you should read this: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the decode to a var...

```
$decodedContent = json_decode($content, true);

foreach ($decodedContent as $currency => $arr) { 
            foreach ($arr as $commodity => $price) { 
                if($currency == "usd" and $commodity =="gold")
              {
                $gold_price = round($price, 2);
              }
            } 
          }
```

Also you should avoid doing a triple loop by making a switch by $commodity in the foreach

```
 if($currency == "usd")
          {
            switch($commodity){
            case 'gold':
            $gold_price = round($price, 2);
            break;
            case 'silver':
            $silver_price = round($price, 2);
            break;
            case 'platinum':
            $platinum_price = round($price, 2);
            break;
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
foreach (json_decode($content, true) as $currency => $arr) { 
    foreach ($arr as $commodity => $price) { 
       if($currency == "usd") and )
       {
            if($commodity =="gold"){
                $gold_price = round($price, 2);
            } elseif($commodity =="platinum"){
                $platinum_price = round($price, 2);
            } elseif($commodity =="silver"){
                $silver_price = round($price, 2);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

This way you only loop through it ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you put gold, silver, and platinum in an array like `$target_commodities` this could be even better, but this will make it so you only have to loop through the JSON once

```
$decoded_json = json_decode($content, true)

$commodity_prices = array(
    'gold' => 0,
    'silver' => 0,
    'platinum' => 0,
);

foreach ($decoded_json as $currency => $arr) { 
    foreach ($arr as $commodity => $price) {
        if ($currency == 'usd') {    
            switch ($commodity) {
            case 'gold':
            case 'silver':
            case 'platinum':
                $commodity_prices[$commodity] = round($price, 2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo('Gold price: ' . $commodity_prices['gold']);
echo('Silver price: ' . $commodity_prices['silver']);
echo('Platinum price: ' . $commodity_prices['platinum']);
```

Comment: And if gold silver and platinum are the only commodity's, you can get rid of the switch case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of your code (condensed), with json_decode once, and without the extra if/foreach loops.

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.xmlcharts.com/cache/precious-metals.php?format=json'); 

// Decode contents    
$json = json_decode($content, true);

if(json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {

    // Define defaults for variables    
    $gold_price = '';
    $silver_price = '';
    $platinum_price = '';

    foreach ($json as $currency => $arr) { 
        foreach ($arr as $commodity => $price) { 
            if($currency == "usd") {
                switch($commodity) {
                    case "gold":
                        $gold_price = money_format('%i', $price);
                        break;
                    case "silver":
                        $silver_price = money_format('%i', $price);
                        break;
                    case "platinum":
                        $platinum_price = money_format('%i', $price);
                        break;
                }
            }
        } 
    }

} else {
    echo 'Invalid JSON';
    exit(0);
}
```